# jquery tooltip does not show up (when mouse over) after change content several times

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tooltip

I add a jquery tooltip on a chart, sometime it doesn't show up and I don't have any error message.

I have a `<div class="chart" title=""></div>` and my project will load one chart in this tag when it does the initial loading. Meanwhile, I add a tooltip

`$('.chart').tooltip({content:'Loading'})` in the same function where it do the initial chart loading.

In another function called `updateChart`, I add the following content to this function:

`$('.chart').tooltip("option","content",'new content')`.

This doesn't work well sometime. The tooltip brokes sometime after several loadings. When I mouse over the `<div class="chart">` tags, the tooltip doesn't appear.

I am not sure why this is the case. I searched over the web, one possibility I can image is that the jquery tooltip conflicts with bootstrap tooltip, so it brokes. However, this doesn't make full sense to me because if it has confliction, i shouldn't even success.

Another guest is that after a few loading, the tooltip is not binding with  tag anymore. I tried to create one tooltip every time when I load the chart and assign content to it every time it is created. But this doesn't solve my problem either. How can I check whether the `<div class="chart">` is still binding with the tooltip in developer tool?

Many thanks if anyone can give me some hint, I really do not why this thing happened, so wired :(.

Comment: If you add elements dynamically, you have to call `.tooltip()` on them after they're added.

Comment: If you tried to do this, show your code. You're probably not doing it right, but we can't tell what you're doing wrong if you don't post it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks very much for your reply, but can you tell me why I need to use .tooltip() after after using .tooltip({content: somevalue}) ? Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: The selector finds all the matching elements at the time you call it, and the tooltip plugin is initialized on those elements. If you load new `.chart` elements later, they won't have the plugin added to them, because they weren't there when you called `.tooltip`.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the tooltip on the `document` first and modify it on the selector load. Please notice the JSON object notation for correct syntax.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
  $('.chart').tooltip({
    content: "This is ToolTip Content"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a class="chart" title="">  
    Mouseover HERE!
</a>
```